# typo3 4.7: how to create a flexform with javascript logic?

Tags: typo3

I work in typo3 4.7, and I have a custom extension, a frontend plugin that the user can put on a page.

In the typo3 backend, in the "Edit Page Content" dialog, the user can parameterize some options for my plugin. Note that I'm not talking about a backend module here. I'm talking about the dialog that appears after Clicking "Add content element/add plugin/XXXXXX/plugin-tab/.

The topmost item is a selection box, and depending on the value chosen there, I want different sets of text fields to be shown. How can I do that in javascript?

- If selection = "1", then show field A, hide fields B,C,D
- If selection
  = "2", then hide field A, show fields B,C, hide D
- If selection = "3", then hide field A, show fields B, hide C, show D

Is there any plugin that can do that? I'd like to have a look how they did it.

Update:
In [this external forum thread from 2009](http://typo3.3.n7.nabble.com/how-to-update-a-flexform-on-a-select-change-td139176.html) someone wanted to something similar. Responders just hinted at solution attemps. Some links now dead

Comment: One way to do this is to use [displayConditions](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Columns/Index.html#displaycond), and then use the property [requestUpdate](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Ctrl/Index.html#ctrl-reference-requestupdate) to trigger reloading the form when the selection changes.

Comment: is it requestUpdate or rather onChange?

Comment: It is a setting in the flexform you can make, you don't really need JavaScript for what you want - TYPO3 comes with that functionality.

Comment: I got it done. Your hint pointed me in the right direction. Thanks! I still don't know all features of typo3 inside and out.